# what is the use of a mini display-in port on a thunderbolt expansion card

Tags: graphics-card, thunderbolt, mini-displayport

I bought a Asus ThunderboltEX 3 card. Mainly to connect thunderbolt hardware to my PC. But it also has a mini display-in that according to the manual you connect to a GPU's VGA I/O with the included cable.

So my question is what can I use it for and how does it work? I have read that I could connect display's to it. So my guess is the GPU would generate the graphic information and send it to ThunderboltEX 3 where it will be send the USB C.

Anyway if someone could explain I would be very grtefull.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must connect the Mini DisplayPort input if you wish to use a Thunderbolt 3 monitor. Otherwise it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jason. So if I understand you right, the Asus ThunderboltEX 3 just transforms the graphics card's output to thunderbolt in order to connect a Thunderbolt monitor. That is why I have to connect the graphic card's output to the mini display input of the ThunderboltEX 3.

Comment: @Santana Yes.  More so combine, than transform.  DisplayPort is a feature of Thunderbolt 3.

Answer (score 0):

With DisplayPort 1.2, you can use a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter cable to plug into a large screen T.V., etc.

[Bing images DisplayPort 1.2 to HDMI](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=displayport+1.2+to+hdmi&qpvt=displayport+1.2+to+hdmi&FORM=IGRE)

PC Magazine article "DMI vs. DisplayPort: Which Should I Use for My PC Monitor"

By Whitson Gordon | September 28, 2018

> Connecting With DisplayPort
>   
>   DisplayPort looks similar to HDMI, but is a different connector more common on 
>   PCs than TVs. It still allows for high-definition video and, in many cases, audio, 
>   but its standards are a bit different. On modern monitors, you'll likely find any of 
>   the following:
>   
>     DisplayPort 1.2: Supports up to 4K at 60Hz, some 1.2a ports may also support AMD's FreeSync

[Specifications](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboard-Accessories/ThunderboltEX-3/specifications/)

> Accessories:
>   1 x mini DisplayPort Cable (links graphics output from motherboard's or discrete graphics card's DisplayPort to the mini DisplayPort IN port on the ThunderboltEX 3 card)

[Thunderbolttechnology.net "FAQs"](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/tech/faq)

> How is Thunderbolt 3 able to connect to every display?
>   
>   Thunderbolt 3 provides DisplayPort, which can natively connect to all displays with 
>   DisplayPort and Mini DisplayPort, and via adapters can connect to all other modern 
>   display interfaces, including HDMI, DVI, and VGA.....

No I am not a bot! I just passed the "choose the buses" in the photo's check. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you a bot?  How does this answer the question?